# JSON array in database is not updating

Tags: javascript, sqlite, express

I have a database of articles with one of the columns being a comment section, stored as an array in JSON format. When a user adds a comment to the article, this is called in the server:

```
app.post("/add-comment", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id;
  const newComment = req.body.comment;

  console.log("Adding comment: (%s) to articleID: %i", newComment, id);
  global.db.run(`
    UPDATE articles
    SET comments = JSON_SET(comments, '$[JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(comments)]', "?")
    WHERE article_id=?`,
    [newComment,id],
    function (err) {
      if (err) {
        next(err); //send the error on to the error handler
      }
    });
});
```

The JSON array already in the database would look like this:

```
["first comment","second comment"]
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range
--> in Statement#run([ 'asd', '3' ], [Function (anonymous)])
```

Is `$[JSON_ARRAY_LENGTH(comments)]` not supposed to add a new element in my array?

Comment: Show the error in your post. Not in your title. And remember to show the full error, not just the summary. And of course: did you remember to log the query before you run it, so you can see what the actual SQL instruction is that you're sending to sqlite? (although to be honest, I'm not sure I understand why you're using JSON_SET at all, you're already working in JS, just create the JSON you need the comment field to be on the JS side and template it in?)

Comment: i'm not sure how to log the query with all the information in. i was using JSON_SET as i was following another example I found on this site, it worked for them so i thought i could do the same and get similar results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`JSON_INSERT()`](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jins) with an array index of `"#"` to append a comment at the end of the json array:

```
UPDATE articles
SET comments = JSON_INSERT(comments, '$[#]', ?)
WHERE article_id=?
```

Comment: removing one of the commas before `'$[#]'` did the trick, thanks